# How to concatenate two words that is having space as a word in to jquery element?

Tags: jquery, html

The below code shows three links to be clicked where each link needed to redirected to div.

```
<div class="paging-links">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="paging-item"><a href="#" class="paging-link active">First Div</a></li>
            <li class="paging-item"><a href="#" class="paging-link">Second Div</a></li>
            <li class="paging-item"><a href="#" class="paging-link">Third Div</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

First Div has some images which are shown when the page loads

```
<div id="gallery-page-first div" class="gallery-page">
...... image set......
```

Second Div has some images which are needed to be shown when the "Second Div" link clicked

```
<div id="gallery-page-second div" class="gallery-page hidden">
...... image set......
```

Third Div has some images which are needed to be shown when the "Third Div" link clicked and vice versa for second and first.

```
<div id="gallery-page-third div" class="gallery-page hidden">
...... image set......
```

My question is *how to get the Div elements with space to concatenate into the below JQuery*?.
(marked using this `<---`)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Handle click on paging links
        $('.paging-link').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var page = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            $('.gallery-page').addClass('hidden');
            $('#gallery-page-' + page).removeClass('hidden'); // <---
            $('.paging-link').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** Still, I'm using `_` character between words, something like

```
<li class="paging-item"><a href="#" class="paging-link active">First_Div</a></li>
```

and

```
<div id="gallery-page-first_div" class="gallery-page">
...... image set......
```

Links are perfectly working, but that does not look good.

Comment: `gallery-page-third div` is an invalid value for `id`; they cannot contain spaces.

Comment: So if I need a div Element that has two words how can I use it in the JQuery

Comment: Use some other character, like `gallery-page-second_div`

Comment: Look into `data-*` attributes instead of using `.text()`. Building a selector based on an element's inner text isn't a great idea as it can change (e.g. if the user uses Chrome's built-in page translate).

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Spaces are not allowed in IDs.

Comment: if you need to use two words, You need to add it by Class! .. Class supports 2 or more words.

Comment: It's also common to use the `href` attribute for this. `href="#divID"`

Comment: @Barmar it is not good to use First_Div in a list element, right?

Answer (score 2):

Put the ID of the DIV in the `href` attribute, rather than using the text.

```
<div class="paging-links">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="paging-item"><a href="#div1" class="paging-link active">First Div</a></li>
            <li class="paging-item"><a href="#div2" class="paging-link">Second Div</a></li>
            <li class="paging-item"><a href="#div3" class="paging-link">Third Div</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="gallery-page">
...... image set......
</div>
<div id="div2" class="gallery-page hidden">
...... image set......
</div>
<div id="div3" class="gallery-page hidden">
...... image set......
</div>
```

Then the jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Handle click on paging links
    $('.paging-link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.gallery-page').addClass('hidden');
        $(page).removeClass('hidden'); // <---
        $('.paging-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: The above method is not worked for me. Still, I'm using `_` character between words , `<li class="paging-item"><a href="#" class="paging-link active">First_Div</a></li>`. That is not looks good.

Comment: `var page = $(this).attr(href);` is this correct or `var page = $(this).attr('href');`?
 is single quotation marks for parameters needed?

Comment: @NIMISHAN, var page = $(this).attr('href'); was correct

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly Understand, You are having problems with like accordion something. 
You can use this snippet. Check this once.

```js
$(".tab-btn li").click(function () {
//alert('ss')
  var e = $(".tab-btn li").index(this);
  $(".tab-btn li").removeClass("active"),
  $(this).addClass("active"),
  $(".tabs").fadeOut(600).hide(),
  $(".tabs:eq(" + e + ")").fadeIn(600).show()
});
```

```css
.tabs{display:none}
.tabs.active{display:block}
.tab-btn li.active{color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-btn">
  <li class="active">Tab 1</li>
  <li>Tab 2</li>
  <li>Tab 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="tabs active">
  <p>Something >> 1</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <p>Something >> 2</p>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  <p>Something >> 3</p>
</div>
```